# How to pass two strings (Username and Password) one by one in the two different text fields (Username and Password) in webdriver (Java)

Tags: webdriver, java

I am having two different Strings by name username and password. And i want to pass these string values one by one (ONLY one value from username and one value from password) into username and password text fields. I tried in two different ways but not sure where i am doing mistake. Below are my codes and O/P result. 
Expected: Two combinations (1st: @ and @, 2nd: test and test).

Expected O/P: username password username password

String[] username={"@", "test"};

String[] password= {"@", "test"};

1st method:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TwoStrings {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String[] username={"@", "test"};
String[] password= {"@", "test"};
WebDriver d =new FirefoxDriver();
d.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/mercurysignon.php");
d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
for(String j:username){
d.findElement(By.name("userName")).clear();
d.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys(j);
System.out.println("userName");
for(int i =0; i<password.length; i++){
d.findElement(By.name("password")).clear();
d.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(password[i]);
System.out.println("password");
}
}
d.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
}
}
```

**O/P:** 
userName
password
password
userName
password
password

2nd method which i tried:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TwoStrings {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String[] username={"@", "test"};
String[] password= {"@", "test"};
WebDriver d =new FirefoxDriver();
d.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/mercurysignon.php");
d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
for(String j:username){
for(String k:password){
d.findElement(By.name("userName")).clear();
d.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys(j);
System.out.println("userName");
d.findElement(By.name("password")).clear();
d.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(k);
System.out.println("password");
}
}
d.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
}
}
```

**O/P:** 
userName
password
userName
password
userName
password
userName
password

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if you want to stick with String[] for you two username and password values here is one approach.  Instead of your current loop I would use a traditional for loop and access the array elements by index in a single loop.   So you code might looks something like this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TwoStrings 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String[] username={"@", "test"};
            String[] password= {"@", "test"};

        WebDriver d =new FirefoxDriver();
        d.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/mercurysignon.php");
        d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            for(int i = 0; i < username.length ; i++)
            {
               d.findElement(By.name("userName")).clear();
               d.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys(username[i]);
               System.out.println(username[i]);
               d.findElement(By.name("password")).clear();
               d.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(password[i]);
               System.out.println(username[i]);

               d.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
             }
    }
}
```

This should run the user name and password combinations in a single loop assuming that is what you were attempting to do.

Here is one alternative using a custom collection and a List<>:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TwoStrings 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        List<LoginData> dataCollection = new ArrayList<LoginData>();
        data.add(new LoginData("username","password"));
        data.add(new LoginData("username1","password2"));


        WebDriver d =new FirefoxDriver();
        d.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/mercurysignon.php");
        d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            for(LoginData data : dataCollection)
            {
               d.findElement(By.name("userName")).clear();
               d.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys(data.get_username());
               System.out.println(data.get_username());
               d.findElement(By.name("password")).clear();
               d.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(data.get_password());
               System.out.println(data.get_password());

               d.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
             }
    }
}

public class LoginData
{
    private String _username;
    private String _password;

    public LoginData(String username, String password)
    {
        this.set_username(username);
        this.set_password(password);    
    }

    public String get_username()
    {
        return _username;
    }

    private void set_username(String _username)
    {
        this._username = _username;
    }

    public String get_password()
    {
        return _password;
    }

    private void set_password(String _password)
    {
        this._password = _password;
    }

}
```

Comment: Dan in my case i have different roles/users (Ex: Admin and Employee- These options are under dropdown) so when you select user/role as Admin and you enter Employee credentials then application will throw an error message. So i am using String [] array in code. (Above url is sample application - just for reference).

Comment: Ok - based on your comment is sounds like you need to modify your looping structure.  I am assuming the order of the usernames and passwords line up so index 0 and 1 in both arrays?  Working from that I will modify my answer.

Comment: AWESOME....!!!! It worked as per my expectation. But if you brief about below logic than its good for me.               `i < username.length` you used only for username but not password?.

Comment: Since the arrays are the same size in this case I am only using it to define the upper bounds of the loop.  So I could have used password.length but it is pretty much interchangeable.  There are two other possible approaches you could take. One would have been to use a Map (key/value pairs).  Or you could have created a custom object to hold the values and stored those in a List<>.

Comment: I am not good coder but I will work on your suggestions. Thanks much friend..

Comment: You were on the right track.  The main problem you had is you were executing a loop inside of another loop.  so they name and passwords got associated more than once.

Comment: Is this correct (List)?.                                    `ArrayList<String> username = new ArrayList<String>();      
username.add("$$$");                                           
username.add("test");                                        
ArrayList<String> password = new ArrayList<String>();       
password.add("@@@");                                        
password.add("test");`

Comment: I added an alternative solution to outline what I was thinking with regards to the list.